# What is the term for any data structure that can store more than one type?

Tags: data-structures

What is the theoretical term for a data structure that stores more than one data type?

i.e. list = [10,"a",7.8,False]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also found this lurking on the net - Heterogeneous Data Structure – Data elements may not be of same data type

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a data structure that can hold more than one data type is called a Polysemy. For example, a list is a Polysemy because it can hold Booleans, integers, strings, and more. A dictionary would not be a Polysemy because it can only hold 2 types of data, strings and integers.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it helped you so it can help the community.

Comment: No problem! Would you mid marking the question as answered if it helped you so it can help the community? Thank you

Comment: I'm new to this platform. I can't see how to mark the question as answered

Comment: Hover over my answer and you should see a checkmark. Click on it and it should mark as answered.

Comment: If you need anymore help, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I have a feeling that because I joined today, the feature is not open to me. I can't see it anywhere. Sorry

Comment: Ok, in about a week or whenever you get a chance please mark the question as answered as it will help the community.

Comment: No probs, will do